# JavaFX2 doesn't run on OS X

Tags: javafx-2

I just installed Java 7 plus JavaFX 2.1 from Oracle on my iMac (Lion).

I had previous developer releases installed before. If I am running a JavaFX2, compilation runs smooth but shortly after starting the application, the application freezes. I can see the icon in the dock and in the taskmanager but I can't select the application, it seems as only half loaded.

On my MBA without any previous JavaFX installations everything runs smoothly.

I highly appreciate any hints and suggestions in order to become JavaFX2 running on the iMac.

Thanks in advance,

Reto

Comment: can you, please, add your MB version, OS version and video card.

Comment: iMac: 2.66 GHz Core i5, 12 GB RAM, OS X 10.7.3, ATI Radeon 4850 (512MB))

Comment: MBA (without problems): 1.86 GHz Core 2 Duo, 4 GB RAM, NVidia GeForce 320 M (256MB)

Comment: Can you, please, also try to run your app with an option `-Dprism.verbose=true` and provide output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release of Java 7 and Java FX 2 was a little delayed on the Mac side.  Java 7 is not the official release for end-users and this includes Mac users.

Mac users can now [download the latest JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html) (including JavaFX 2) from Oracle's download page!